# How To Search data from RecyclerView Retrofit Kotlin Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, search, android-recyclerview, retrofit

How to search for data in RecyclerView?

I have model like this and I get data with retrofit. I have to make RecyclerView with model data like this and how to make Search from RecyclerView?

```
data class ListArticle(
@SerializedName("status") val status : String,
@SerializedName("totalResults") val totalResults : Int,
@SerializedName("articles") val articles : List<Articles>
)

data class Source (

@SerializedName("id") val id : String,
@SerializedName("name") val name : String
)

data class Articles (

@SerializedName("source") val source : Source,
@SerializedName("author") val author : String,
@SerializedName("title") val title : String,
@SerializedName("description") val description : String,
@SerializedName("url") val url : String,
@SerializedName("urlToImage") val urlToImage : String,
@SerializedName("publishedAt") val publishedAt : String,
@SerializedName("content") val content : String
)
```

Comment: That's a huge question! What have you searched so far? What have you done so far? Is the API you are connecting to the one filtering, or are you getting everything and filtering it locally? Can you narrow the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have to solve this question and I'm sorry for not completed question

just added this to your adapter

```
fun getFilter(): Filter? {
    return articleFilter
}

private val articleFilter: Filter = object : Filter() {
    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults? {
        val filteredList: MutableList<Articles> = ArrayList()
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(articles)
        } else {
            val filterPattern =
                constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }
            for (item in articles) {
                if (item.title.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item)
                }
            }
        }
        val results = FilterResults()
        results.values = filteredList
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(
        constraint: CharSequence?,
        results: FilterResults
    ) {
        searchArticles = results.values as List<Articles>
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

fun setData(article: List<Articles>){
    searchArticles = article
    notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```